# How to determine which project triggered build in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

does anyone know whether it is possible to tell what project triggered build in CruiseControl.NET, especially when I have a set InnerTriggers. Can you set a name for the trigger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Parameter Triggers](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Parameter+Trigger), which are introduced with CCNET 1.5.